# Raw string in Regular expression Python

Tags: python

In python regular expression, raw string behavior is different.

```
import re
m = re.match(r"\n","C:\some\nDay\n")
print(m)
a= re.match("\n", "C:\some\nDay\n")
print(a)
```

In the first expression, it should consider \n as normal text and return the match position.
but in both expression None is the output.

Comment: The behavior is different, but the results are the same? Care to revise your question?

Comment: `match()` will work if you for instance do `re.match(r'[^\n]*\n+', 'C:\some\nDay\n', re.M)`. But also know that `C:\some` is not escaped, meaning `\s` is escaped.

Comment: re.match(r'[^\n]*\n+', 'C:\some\nDay\n', re.M)                                                    and re.match('[^\n]*\n+', 'C:\some\nDay\n', re.M) --> results are same